# Run Python script on startup

Tags: ubuntu, python, startup

Running on Ubuntu Karmic. I need to execute the following (updated) script at boot time

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/scripts
# Description: Starts Python scripts
# ————————————————–
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: Scripts
# Required-Start: $network $local_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Description: Start Python scripts to provide mapping services
### END INIT INFO

case $1 in
  start)
    # echo -n ¨Starting Mapping service: ¨
/usr/local/bin/liteserv.py /home/myUN/bin/mapnik/my_osm.xml --caching --debug=False
;;
  stop)
# echo -n ¨Stoping Mapping service: ¨
/usr/local/bin/liteserv.py /home/myUN/bin/mapnik/my_osm.xml --caching --debug=False
;;
  restart)
# echo -n ¨Retarting Mapping service: ¨
/usr/local/bin/liteserv.py /home/myUN/bin/mapnik/my_osm.xml --caching --debug=False
;;
  *)
# echo ¨Usage: scripts {start|stop|restart}¨
exit 1
esac
```

Have placed it into /etc/init.d
Registered it with

```
sudo update-rc.d scripts defaults
```

But nothing happens on boot. I have tried looking in the logs but I can't find anything.  Both scripts and liteserv.py are marked as executable.

As per Andy Smith's response, When I run:

```
/etc/init.d/scripts start
```

I now get the program running correctly (after correcting the bad quotes).
However, it still does not run the program on bootup.

Comment: It may sound stupid, but have you checked that the script is executable?

Comment: Also, I think you mean `sudo update-rc.d scripts default` (without the `s`)?

Comment: Additional to the above comment, have you tried running it manually with `/etc/init.d/scripts start`?

Comment: you should specify "at startup" a bit further... people might think "startup of when they log in".

Comment: From the help it appears ¨s¨ is required:
    update-rc.d [-n] <basename> defaults [NN | SS KK]

Comment: @P Hemans: your quote chars look .. strange, are these really in your script or do you use `"` there?

Answer (score 7):

This is bizarre, but unless it is something that Stack Exchange is doing, I think the problem you are having is that you are using "fancy quotes" rather than `""`.

Whatever editor you are using may have replaced the standard quote character(Unicode U+0022) with stylized open and close quotes (U+201C and U+201D).  `sh` doesn't like this very much.  When I replace these stylized quotes with "normal quotes" your code works fine (with the small exception that I don't have the .py file it calls).

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. Wasn´t the entire answer but it sure helped. I had copied and modified the code off the web and that is where the fancy quotes came from. However, the problem turned out to be the statement:  
´case “$1″ in ´
It should have been  

´case $1 in ´

Comment: Well, the quotes should work around the `$1` provided that they aren't fancy quotes.  Glad to hear it is worked out.

Comment: Turned out that my keyboard driver was messed up. Was wondering why I had to type " twice to get it to work:  
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-299219.html  
Still having the original problem though, where the program won't run on boot.

Comment: @P Hemans: If you used a proper editor with syntax highlight (i.e. Vi) that could have been very obvious :P

Answer (score 2):

You can add your stuff to `/etc/rc.local`.

Otherwise, you could place your script into `/etc/init.d/`, `chmod +x` it and then run `update-rc.d FOO defaults`.

Comment: Yes that is pretty much what I have done. Starting it with "etc/init.d/scripts start" leads to errors as described in my comments (above)

Answer (score 1):

Your script indicates it wants to be started in runlevels 3 and 5, stopped in runlevels 1 and 2 (plus 0 and 6 which are shutdown and reboot), and no opinion in runlevel 4. Ubuntu boots to runlevel 2 by default (I think this is still true with Upstart). So unless you set a different default runlevel your script won't run. In the script headers, use

```
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
```

Comment: I have changed it as per your instructions, but I think I may have another problem as the script won't run with "start" (see above).

Answer (score 0):

By adding:

```
exec > /tmp/debug-my-script.txt 2>&1
```

at the beginning of the scripts file I was able to at least trap the error messages that was coming from the Python program (an authentication error with postgres). So the script is running at boot time (after much community input). It just fails during the run (which is a different problem).